# Using interceptors for dependent scoped beans in vaadin CDI

Tags: java, vaadin, cdi

I'm currently trying to implement logging via an interceptor with Vaadin CDI (running in Wildfly 9.0.1). The interceptor works well for beans with a proxy (I need to annotate the class with vaadins @NormalXXX-Scopes), but if the class has no scope specified (implicit @Dependent), no proxy is created and the interceptor doesn't work.

How can I enable interceptors for Dependent-Scoped beans?

Comment: You cannot, only normal scoped beans can have interceptors.  Why can you not make this a normal scoped bean?

Comment: @John Your comment is really an answer :) Please consider posting it.

Comment: @JohnAment There are only two normal scopes: NormalViewScoped and NormalUiScoped. What if I want to have something like a Dependent scope? If I understand it correctly, ViewScoped and UiScoped instances are shared, but I want to make sure that every bean gets its own instace of my bean.

Comment: Could you update your question with a bit more information about why you're concerned about sharing? ViewScoped is basically for the duration a page is open, so it may suit your needs but your comment is a bit confusing/concerning.